# How to terminate a listening TCP Server with keyboard input in C++

Tags: c++, linux, server, serversocket

I am trying to find a way to close a server safely while it is listening for incoming client connection without using the classic <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in linux. I would like to terminate the program for example by keyboard input of <kbd>Q</kbd> or `-quit` etc... and **do so instantly after pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>, not after accepting, for example, a client connection**. How should I implement this?
Here is my sample code.

```cpp
    int startSocketConnection() {
        socketFD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

        //TODO exceptions
        if (socketFD < 0) {
            std::cout << "\nError establishing socket...\nexiting..." << std::endl;
            return (-1);
        }
        std::cout << "\nSocket server has been created..." << std::endl;
        server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
        server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
        server_addr.sin_port        = htons(portNum);

        //TODO exceptions
        if ( (bind(socketFD, (struct sockaddr*) &server_addr, sizeof(server_addr))) < 0 ) {
            std::cout << "Error binding connection, Socket has already been established" << std::endl;
            return (-1);
        }

        std::cout << "Listening for incoming client connection..." << std::endl;
        listen(socketFD, 1);

        size = sizeof(client_addr);
        while (sessionActive) {
            newSocketFD = accept(socketFD, (struct sockaddr *) &client_addr, &size);
            if (newSocketFD < 0) error("ERROR on accept");
            //fork() returns child pid to parent, 0 to the child process.
            pid = fork();
            if (pid < 0) error("ERROR on fork");
            //if child process...
            if (pid == 0)  {
                close(socketFD);

                //process client query...
                sessionActive = dostuff(newSocketFD);

                signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
                std::cout << "Child process terminated!" << std::endl;
                exit(0);
            }
            else {
                close(newSocketFD);
            }
        }
        close(socketFD);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: If you have read a few books or tutorials I assume you seen the use of *non-blocking* sockets and the *`select`* call? Both are useful aids to help you solve your problem. Also remember that sockets and files are all the same in POSIX (like Linux) environments, both are *descriptors*. Also remember that standard input is a file that can be read from like any other (for example from the `STDIN_FILENO` descriptor).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Unfortunately I dont have any knowledge on writting a network server. Even the one I wrote is pretty much copy pasted. Thanks for the information though.

Answer (score 2):

You need to either add another thread that reads from stdin and unceremoniously exits your application when it sees those commands, or change your code to use a command like [`select`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/select) or [`poll`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/poll) to see which descriptors have input available: add the descriptor for `stdin` (for your purposes, you can trust it to be 0) alongside the descriptor for the listening socket, and when either or both have input events your `select` or `poll` will return and - if it tells you stdin has data - you can read from it without blocking: if you see your termination command, exit.

For `select`/`poll`, you should set the socket you're calling `accept` on to non-blocking, as it's possible to be notified of an incoming connection attempt but by the time you go to `accept` that connection may have already failed - you don't want `accept` to block and stop your `select` or `poll` call monitoring `stdin` too for you.

Of the two, the extra thread is easiest - here's a minimal program illustrating how to start it and have it monitor stdin while your main thread's doing its own stuff.  On Linux, link with `-lpthread`.

```
#include <thread>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h> // for sleep

int main()
{
    std::thread t{
        [] {
            std::string s;
            while (std::cin >> s)
                if (s == "exit")
                {
                    std::cout << "exit command given on stdin\n";
                    exit(0);
                }
        }
    };
    t.detach();

    while (true)
    {
        sleep(2);
        std::cout << "beat\n";
    }
}
```

(It does get a bit more complicated if you want "orderly" shutdown, where destructors for objects in the main thread are guaranteed to run....)

Comment: Thanks for replying. That is indeed more complicated that I expected. For just adding a simple extra functionality!

Comment: The thread approach is pretty easy - see example code I've appended to my answer.